# Wai development server and cabal sandbox

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm writing a small [Scotty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty) app and have decided after using yesod that I cannot live without [wai-handler-devel](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-handler-devel) to live-reload code for me. I'm using `cabal sandbox` like a good little boy, but every time I run my development executable (through `cabal run`), I get the error `Could not find module Web.Scotty`. However, when I build the application executable (not the development executable), it all runs fine.

The two executables have identical dependencies in the `cabal` file. The app executable has a `main` that uses `wai`'s `run` handler, while the development executable uses `runQuit` from `wai-handler-devel`.

I assume this is a sandboxing issue, because the [usual setup](https://github.com/martinrehfeld/wai-example) seems to be to use `runhaskell` to execute the development server script - but since my application is sandboxed, it doesn't even find the `DevelServer` import.